# Separate NSData into smaller NSMutableData objects

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, nsdata

I am unsure of how to separate a NSData object into smaller parts so that I can send it over bluetooth. I believe it is a method similar to this:

```
- (void)getBytes:(void *)buffer range:(NSRange)range
```

I do not know what to pass in for the buffer. Do I just pass in a NSMutableData object to hold the bytes that I pull out of the original NSData?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-subdataWithRange:` method.